# prove $\dim\mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2]=3$ from first principles

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

Since $\dim R[X] =\dim R+1$ for any Noetherian ring $R$, the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2]$ must have dimension 3. But how can this be proved 'from first principles', i.e. without using any big theorems from commutative algebra?

Clearly the dimension is at least 3, e.g. using the chain $\{0\},(2),(2,X_1),(2,X_1,X_2)$. To prove it's at most 3, I tried assuming the existence of a length-4 chain and then quotienting by the bottom element to get a chain in $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2]/(f)$ for $f$ irreducible, but couldn't get anywhere from there. Can we easily prove something about the structure of the prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2]$?

Many thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Are you able to prove any maximal ideal in ${\mathbf Z}[X_1,X_2]$ contains a prime number $p$, and that for any prime number $p$ the prime ideal $(p)$ in ${\mathbf Z}[X_1,X_2]$ is minimal (it contains no prime ideal other than itself)? Once you have those, your problem reduces to the task of showing ${\mathbf F}_p[X_1,X_2]$ has dimension 2 for any prime $p$, and here you're dealing with the polynomial ring over a field. This would carry over to ${\mathbf Z}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$; that it has dimension $n+1$ reduces to a proof that ${\mathbf F}_p[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ has dimension $n$ for any prime $p$.

Comment: @KCd: Thanks for this! I think some fiddling about is required, adding $(p)$ and then quotienting by it, but it works. If you turn this into an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: @KCd: Nice proof! We may replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by any PID here, right?

Comment: @HarryMacpherson: what do you mean by "adding $(p)$"? You don't get to "add $(p)$" to a maximal ideal: it already contains $p$ for one prime number $p$. That needs to be shown.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Good question. Alas, the answer is no. For the PID consider ${\mathbf Z}_p$, the $p$-adic integers. The ring ${\mathbf Z}_p[x]$ contains a maximal ideal $(px-1)$ (it's maximal since ${\mathbf Z}_p[1/p] = {\mathbf Q}_p$ is a field) and this has no prime of  ${\mathbf Z}_p$. Similarly, in ${\mathbf Z}_p[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ the maximal ideal $(px_1-1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ has no prime of ${\mathbf Z}_p$. Over ${\mathbf Z}$ what I said before uses that there are infinitely many prime numbers, i.e., that the fraction field of ${\mathbf Z}$ is not of the form ${\mathbf Z}[1/N]$.